# Angular statistics doesn't make sense

Tags: statistics, mean, angle, direction

I calculated a mean angle of below two angles.

337.477792
324.8119785

I used the formula to calculate a mean angle (see below #Distribution of the mean)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_statistics

What I got was 28.85511475 / -28.8551147. The values don't look right ... Wonder if someone can explain this result for me? Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The values don't look right

Angles that differ by `360` are equivalent. So, `-28.8551147 == 331.145`, which is the arithmetic mean of the two values you provided. If you would like to ensure that your values are always in `[0,360)`, you should add `360` if the values are less than `0`.

Comment: Actually, I have an additional question. I am still trying to figure out how I can program to select correct answer between Acos and Asin. For example, I get the numbers like these after running the angular statistics formula. [Acos is 155.470936479, Asin is 24.5290635212]. For now I can determine which is correct by looking at the original angles. I wonder how I can program to automatically select the correct one?